# How to deal with quotes that aren't marked aus such?

Tags: discussion

The first paragraph of [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17954/issue-in-crest-factor) seems to be a verbal quote from [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor) but is not marked up as quote. I assume this is not accepted because it is plagiarism?

Before editing the question I'd like to make sure how to proceed. Should we

- change the markup and add the source
- delete the quotation

I guess the first one would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, just edit it to indicate that it's a quote, and link to the source. It seems innocuous enough in this case (esp. in a question).

On the other hand, we've run into a few answers that were entirely from Wikipedia (without quote or attribution), and those should definitely be flagged for moderator attention. Although, even in those cases, it would be reasonable to do an edit to mark it as a quote (in addition to the flag)--even if it might end up getting deleted eventually.